# Finding whether $\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1*11}{3!}+\frac{1*11*21}{5!}+...+\frac{1*11*21*...*(10n-9)}{(2n-1)!}+...$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I used the ratio test and it diverges... yet my book says it converges. The way my book presents the question is this:

$$\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1*11}{3!}+\frac{1*11*21}{5!}+...+\frac{1*11*21*...*(10n-9)}{(2n-1)!}+...$$

It doesn't state that the numerator is a factorial. I just assumed it was. How do  I solve this? Also if it's not a factorial then what is it?

Comment: In your questions, it is frequently hard to know whether you mean the sequence or the series.  Please clarify.  Also, the terms in the header do not match the series in the body of your question.

Comment: @lulu Is it a series only when it has the $\sum$ symbol? I figure the question in my book is refering to the series. I can add the symbol to the title

Comment: Yes, you should indicate it with the $\sum$ symbol.  Again, though, the header does not match the body. $(10n-9)!=(10n-9)\times (10n-8)\times \cdots \times 3\times 2\times 1$

Comment: It's not a factorial.  In a factorial, there are no integers skipped.

Comment: @saulspatz Then what is it?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding some notation? Why are you writing the $(10n-9)!$ as $1$, $1\times 11$, $1 \times 11 \times 21$...? Why not as $1$, $11!$, $21!$...?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire It's just an expression.  Not every expression has a name.

Comment: @roundsquare Because I thought it was a factorial. Let me edit it

Comment: "*If it is not a factorial then what is it?*" You could follow the generalization of the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and write this as the multifactorial $(10n-9)!_{(10)}$

Comment: The numerator $=\prod_{k=1}^n (10k-9)$   That's it.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that the statement has a numerator like $1\cdot11\cdot21$ and you are interpreting that as a factorial. It is not a factorial (not $(10n-9)!$).

To use the Ratio Test, examine all the simplification that exists in
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{a_n}&=\frac{1\cdot11\cdot21\cdot\cdots\cdot(10n-9)(10n+1)}{(2n+1)!}\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!}{1\cdot11\cdot21\cdot\cdots\cdot(10n-9)}\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\frac{10n+1}{(2n+1)(2n)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: *examine all the simplification that exists in*, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Like how the one $11$ that I wrote cancels with the other $11$ that I wrote.

Comment: Just for completeness, it is worth pointing out that this goes to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't understand what you did. Why $a_{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{a_n}$?

Comment: Isn't that what you do when you set out to apply the ratio test? Maybe you prefer it written as $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Since each term is itself a fraction, I write it that way to avoid writing a four-leveled fraction.